# Android: stop Onclick delay

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I want to fire an intent when clicking 5 times. The problem is when I click 3 times and pause for a while and again hit 2 times the intent is fired...

I want it only when clicking continuously 5 times..

```
static int i = 0;

public void onClick(View view) {
    i++;
    if (i == 5) {
        i = 0;
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity, loginActivity.class);
        activity.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to configure the max delay between clicks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the timestamp of the last click and reset the click counter when the delay since last click is above a threshold:

```
private static final double MAX_CLICK_DELAY = 500; // 500ms
private double lastClickTime = 0;
private int i = 0;

public void onClick(View view) {
    double currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if(currentTime - lastClickTime > MAX_CLICK_DELAY) {
        i = 0;
    }

    lastClickTime = currentTime;

    i++;
    if (i == 5) {
        i = 0;
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity, loginActivity.class);
        activity.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```